# Delete rows from table with few user records

Tags: sql, postgresql, dml

Having this table:

```
 id    |    lat     |    lon     | timestamp  
---------+------------+------------+------------
 5590761 | 41.0106651 | -8.4618407 | 1491071642
 5590761 | 41.0088282 | -8.4613129 | 1491071670
 5590761 | 41.0081011 | -8.4626845 | 1491071763
 5590761 |  41.008415 | -8.4621233 | 1491071767
 5590761 | 41.0084717 |   -8.46211 | 1491071768
 5590761 |  41.008525 | -8.4620333 | 1491071769
 5590761 |   41.00859 | -8.4619783 | 1491071770
 5590761 |  41.008635 |  -8.461875 | 1491071771
 5590761 | 41.0087083 | -8.4616717 | 149107177
```

Some records are having few instances. I want to delete all records where unique `id` count is less than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery in `delete`:

```
delete from t
    where t.id in (select t2.id
                   from t t2
                   group by t2.id
                   having count(*) < 10
                  );
```

If you only want to remove the rows in a `select` query, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt < 10
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the second option as you suggest.